# Creating native plugins to implement missing functions of the official Unity Facebook SDK

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I want to give the possibility to the players of my game, to publish to their Facebook feed images and videos stored on their device.

The Facebook SDK does not seem to provide this feature through [`FB.FeedShare`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.FeedShare). Only already hosted media can be referenced in the `mediaSource` field.

Several questions have been asked about this subject ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38269611/using-fb-feedshare-and-including-the-upload-of-an-image), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23912618/unity-facebook-sdk-can-not-post-picture-with-fb-feed/32264318#32264318), [3](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/111790/how-to-share-image-in-persistentdatapath-to-facebook-feed))

However, the [Android SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#model) and [iOS SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios#model) **does** provide it. Isn't the Facebook SDK a simple "abstract layer" wrapping the native SDKs? Why all the native SDK features haven't been implemented?

---

<s>I **know** an alternative solution would be to upload the media using the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) and reference from the `FB.FeedShare` function.</s>

EDIT: As mentionned by @misorude, [the `publish_actions` permission has been removed](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/24/new-facebook-platform-product-changes-policy-updates/)

---

## TL;DR

Is it possible to create the Android and iOS plugins that would call the native functions used to share a media stored on the device of the users?

If so, do you know how is it possible to "reference" the native Facebook SDKs without bundling them into the plugins I will create? (Since they are already in the Unity Facebook SDK in my project).

EDIT: [Seems like someone already tried to create a wrapper, but "it didn't play nice"](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-for-unity/issues/163#issuecomment-423547704)

I am also open to other suggestions. My final goal is to let the user publish a video. I would love to use intents to open the Facebook app, but iOS does not have such feature.

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Facebook has removed `publish_actions` permission, so you can not post or upload anything in the name of a user any more via API (exception - live videos.)